# Curved dashed line in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, photoshop-effects, shapes

I have made a shape and did 'Stroke Path' to paint it with the brush. I want to make the shape a dashed line so I set the Shape Dynamics and the Angle Jitter to 'Direction'. When I paint the shape, this is the result:

[image: Curved Line]

The blue middle line should be following the path. How can I do that?

It should be something like this:

[image: Curbed Line 2]

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have Illustrator? would be easier

Comment: What version of Photoshop? Vector paths in Photoshop CS6 or newer can do this easily.

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I don't have:( Is there an easy Photoshop solution? I have Photoshop CS6 Version 13!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Photoshop CS6 or newer, you can simply set the **Stroke Options** for a vector path....

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'm new in Photoshop so I don't know exactly what to do. I have made a path. If I click the Pen Tool there is an option to select Shape instead of Path. But when I click Shape I dont get the options to change the Fill, Stroke and Border options. They are disabled...